# Angular error: 'mdb-select' is not a known element

Tags: angular, mdbootstrap

I am using Angular's MDB pro version but I am facing strange error: mdb-select is now a known element

I am assuming that I am missing some import, but i don't know which

My component.html

```
  <mdb-form-control>
  <mdb-select>
    <mdb-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">{{
      option.label
    }}</mdb-option>
  </mdb-select>
  <label mdbLabel class="form-label">Example label</label>
</mdb-form-control>
```

This is my app.module.ts file with my imports

```
    import { LOCALE_ID, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
    registerLocaleData(localeSl);

    import { MdbFormsModule } from 'mdb-angular-ui-kit/forms';
    import { MdbAutocompleteModule } from 'mdb-angular-ui-kit/autocomplete';
    import { MdbAccordionModule } from 'mdb-angular-ui-kit/accordion';
    import { MdbTooltipModule } from 'mdb-angular-ui-kit/tooltip';

    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

    import { SpinnerComponent } from './components/spinner/spinner.component';
    import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { HttpIntercepter } from './interceptor/http-interceptor';
```

And my package.json file if something is not installed right maybr

```
 {
"name": "search",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
"test": "ng test",
"build:elements": "ng build --output-hashing none && node build.js"
 },
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
  "@angular/cdk": "^12.0.0",
  "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
  "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
  "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
  "@angular/http": "^7.1.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
  "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
  "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
  "chart.js": "^3.1.1",
  "concat": "^1.0.3",
  "mdb-angular-ui-kit": 
  "git+https://oauth2:H5cd9vDAeF4zLr17T9B9@git.mdbootstrap.com/mdb/angular/mdb5/prd/mdb5- 
  angular-ui-kit-pro-essential",
  "mdb-ui-kit": "git+https://oauth2:H5cd9vDAeF4zLr17T9B9@git.mdbootstrap.com/mdb/standard/mdb- 
  ui-kit-pro-essential#3.8.1",
  "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
  "tslib": "^2.3.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.13",
  "@angular/cli": "~12.2.13",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
  "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
  "typescript": "~4.3.5"
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:
I needed to import this to my app.module.ts file

```
import { MdbSelectModule } from 'mdb-angular-ui-kit/select';
```